# Merging/Compressing attributes in a single vector shapefile QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

Using QGIS v 2.18.10 
I'm currently working with a vector shapefile that represents zones in a municipality. I've had to create and edit polygons representing these zones. I'm looking to compress/simplify my attribute table so that each zone appears in the attribute table once. 
[image: A picture showing the attribute table related to my question]

For example, in the image above the attribute value "Residential Scheme Area" is there several times, I want that value to be there only once.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the create multipart polygon tool under Vector > Geometry Tools > Single Part to multipart. In the tool select your field "Zone Name" as *unique id field*. This will create a multi-polygon for each class you have.

However be aware, that with this method, information regarding indivual features will be lost.